# postgresql pass table reference to the function

Tags: postgresql, reference

How can I pass table reference to the function? I tried following code but I'm getting errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_(text,n VARCHAR(32),s VARCHAR(32),val int) RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
  DECLARE
    _table ALIAS FOR $1;
  BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '_table = %', _table;
...


SELECT merge_('testtable','h','a',50000);
```

NOTICE:  _table = testtable

This works fine, but when I try to execute a command I get an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_(text,n VARCHAR(32),s VARCHAR(32),val int) RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
 DECLARE
    _table ALIAS FOR $1;
 BEGIN
    UPDATE _table ....
```

> ERROR:  relation "_table" does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution in dynamic commands has to be done using the `EXECUTE` command:

```
EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(_table) || ' ....';
```

You can check the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Wherever you want to use a parameter to insert a relation or column name into a dynamic command you should use the `quote_ident()` function. Other text elements (e.g. `WHERE column_name = parameter_2`) should be inserted with the `quote_literal()` function. Both of these functions help to avoid pesky conflicts (like double-quoting reserved words) and guard against SQL-injection.